# Is there a term for the grammatical/rhetorical construction of "He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, relative-clauses, rhetoric

Is there a term for the construction of specifying someone or something solely via a relative clause without explicitly naming it, as in the example in the title - either at the level of grammar or of rhetoric? This seems like the kind of thing that there'd be an obscure Latin word for. It's kind of like an epithet, but not quite, because you *only* have the epithet and not the primary name itself.

Comment: Allegedly this can be referred to as "voldemorting" (ironic use of the name of he-who-must-not-be-named) although it seems to refer to specific instances such as avoiding web searches, rather than the more general case, so I'm not sure it's an exact fit: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/voldemorting.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it is a case of [Antonomasia](https://literaryterms.net/antonomasia/):

> a literary term in which a descriptive phrase replaces a person’s name.  Antonomasia can range from lighthearted nicknames to epic names.

> The phrase antonomasia is derived from the Greek phrase antonomazein meaning “to name differently.”

Examples:

> Rather than calling the dangerous man by name, all must call him “You-Know-Who” or “He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named.” This usage of antonomasia emphasizes just how dangerous the man is, as most wizards and witches are too afraid to say his actual name aloud.

(literaryterms.net)

Comment: This is a hypernym. 'The Bard of Avon', a famous example, like many does not include the relative clause OP specifies.

Answer (score 0):

At the level of grammar rather than rhetoric, it seems that the construction that I described in the body of my question is called a "[free relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Bound_and_free)".

The example that I gave in the title technically doesn't actually qualify, because of the presence of the pronoun "he", but semantically, it's a similar idea. (I think that in that example, the pronoun "he" is serving as a kind of "minimally semantic placeholder word" that's primarily there for a syntactic reason, and not to convey information about the person himself.)

Comment: I think you should post this as a comment or a P.S. under your question rather than an answer.

Comment: @user66974 Why do you think so? It seems like more of an answer to me, albeit one answering a different aspect of the question than yours.

Comment: The string is usually considered a single lexeme (so we have "Beware He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named"): a weighty compound proper noun/name.

Answer (score 0):

That phase, I think, refers specifically to the Jewish religious convention of considering Jehovah's (Yahweh's) name as being too easily devalued by feeling free to speak it in regular conversation. There is a name for that. "Tetragram" or something like that. I understand that you are thinking of a more  general term though.

Comment: Hello, Joan. As you haven't given an actual answer for this question, the above should not be presented in an 'answer' slot. When you have 50 rep points, you can add tangential but relevant thoughts in 'comments'.

Comment: The example given in the question is actually from Harry Potter. It's what some people call [Voldemort.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_Voldemort)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/415693)